# discord.py giving role issue

Tags: python, discord

I was planning on making a mute command but I have a big issue and I had no clue on what to do.
Code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Mod")
async def mute(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    role = 730016083871793163
    #h = 3600 #seconds
    #m = 60 #seconds
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're supplying an `int` object rather than a `role` object. Your `int` object doesn't have an attribute `id`, but `role` does.

To get the role object, you can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.utils.get).

```
roleobject = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id=role)
await user.add_roles(roleobject)
```